# How can i update header table Status as Closed comparing with detail table Status in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

`Header` table:

```
HeadeID   Status
----------------
1          Open
```

`Detail` table:

```
DetailID HeaderID Status
-------------------------
1            1      Close
2            1      Close
```

Comment: What are u asking? Please simplify the question.

Comment: If the header status is entirely defined by the detail status then ideally, don't *store* the header status at all.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows for the use of triggers. In simple terms, a trigger is a stored procedure which executes on update of a table. You typically use triggers to enforce business rules/logic.

Therefore to apply to your situation place a Trigger on the Details table, which will check if all rows for the current HeaderID have been set to Closed then update the Header table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Detail_Update_Header
ON Detail
AFTER Insert, Update
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @currentHeaderID int;

SELECT @currentHeaderID = i.HeadeID from inserted i;

IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Detail WHERE HeaderID = @currentHeaderID) > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Detail WHERE HeaderID = @currentHeaderID AND Status = 'Closed'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE Header 
    SET Status = 'closed';
END
END
GO
```

Comment: The Update query could be simplified/Enhansed, but it should deliver what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You need something like that if i understand correctly:

```
UPDATE dbo.Header  
    set Status = b.Status
    from  dbo.Header H
    inner join dbo.Detail b ON
    b.HeaderID = H.HeaderID
```

Comment: If you define an alias `from dbo.Header H`, you need to use that alias in the `UPDATE`, too - `UPDATE H SET .....`

Comment: I don't think that's mandatory. It's best practice yes, but the query parses successfully.

Comment: Ah - OK - you're right, SQL Server handles this without a hitch - learned something new again, today! :-)

Comment: This query will give the wrong result. For example, if the Detail table had three items with the Status of ('Closed','Open','Closed') the matching header status would be set to 'Closed'.